# C# (Ошибка CS0118: "..." задан как "тип", но используется как "переменная")

Tags: c#

Кормпилятор пишет ошибку: CS0118: "r_handler.Risk" является "тип", но используется как "переменная".

Погуглил в Интернете, но похожего не нашел. На [официальном сайте](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0118) описание содержит пример, совсем явный, с моей точки зрения, но мне он не совсем помог.

У меня есть класс угроз, содержащий конструктор:

```
public Risk(string id, string v, string l, string p)
    {
        ID = id;
        V = Convert(v);
        L = Convert(l);
        P = Convert(p);
        R = V*L*P;
        //XmlWriter(V, L, P, R, MainForm.Xml_P);
    }
```

В обработчике нажатия на button1 вызывается конструктор, где в качестве аргументов для параметров используются данные, введенные в textBoxы:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Risk(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox5.Text); // CS0118
    }
```

Помогите разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: названия типов и переменных не может совпадать. скорей всего это 'Risk'. наверняка объявили класс с таким именем. или переменную Risk объявили, а тут и функция с таким же именем.

Comment: В C# все классы принято инициализировать, то есть `Risk risk = new Risk(...);` Сейчас же вы используете конструктор класса без инициализации...

Comment: Знаете, а я об этом и не подумал. Конструктор ведь метод, вот я на автомате и вызвал его как обычный метод. Спасибо.

Comment: Единственное что, так это вопрос ссылки на объект. Допустим я создал один  риск, ввел данные и в данном случае `risk` указывает на один объект в хипе, но ведь при введении новых значений и нажатии на кнопку я просто изменю объект ссылки `risk` так, что создам новый риск со старой переменной-ссылкой на него, а старый уберется из памяти. Так ведь? Мне нужно создавать коллекцию?

Comment: `Так ведь?` Примерно так, старый уберется из памяти, когда до него доберётся сборщик мусора. `Мне нужно создавать коллекцию? ` Возможно. Смотря, что вы дальше хотите с этим делать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.